# rails ajax update and list same page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

my requirement: list and edit form on the same page
[image]

whenever user clicks on 'Edit' button, form edit will be showed(default hide) and data in form will be filled with data from row that was clicked.After user edit name and click 'Save' button->row table will be update without refresh page.

File index.html.haml

```
%label.lblCapTbl Client Organizations
  .edit_client_org
    #ShowHideForm
      %strong Edit Client Organization
      .client_orgs_edit_from
        = render :partial => 'edit'
.wrapper-table
  %table#tbl-orgs.table.table-striped
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Client Organizations
        %th Client Account Directors
        %th
        %th
      %tbody
        = render @client_orgs
```

File _edit.html.haml

```
#form_edit_client_org.formEditShow
  = form_for(@client_org,remote: true) do |f|
    #error_explanation
    .form_edit_org
      =f.label :"Name of Client Organization"
      =f.text_field :name ,:autofocus => true ,class: "input_name",placeholder: "Name"
     %br
      =f.label :"Client Account Director(email address)"
     %ul
    .btn_form_add
      = button_tag "Cancel", type: :button, id: "cancelForm", class: "btn"
      = f.submit "Save", :name => 'done',class:"btn"
```

File _client_org.html.haml

```
%tr{:id => "client_org_#{client_org.id}"}
  %td= client_org.name
  %td
    = client_org.users.first.email
  %td
    = link_to "Edit", edit_org_path(client_org), :remote => true,class: 'btn link_edit_client_org'
```

When user presses 'Edit' button.File ClientOrgController

```
def edit
 @client_org = ClientOrg.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @client_org, status: :created }
 end
end

def update
  //TODO
end
```

ajax

```
$('.link_edit_client_org').on('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    $(".edit_client_org").show();
    $('input[name="client_org[name]"]').val(data.name);

});
```

**My question**

when I press 'Save' button on Edit form --> ajax call create action instead of update action  inside ClientOrgController?.I found out that in form edit @client_org variable always nil because in edit function( in ClientOrgControler) I return json data which needed to fill in edit form.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why request JSON instead of just requesting the HTML edit form and rendering it?  If you do use JSON as you are now, you could always update the action of the form with the new url, as you are already doing now for name.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain more?